# PropertyChange Listener for icons

Tags: java, swing, propertychangelistener

I am trying to write a `PropertyChange` Listener which detects whether a JButton has an ImageIcon or not.

`"icon"` is a beans property but I can't seem to add `iconListener` or something equivalent to the `PropertyChangeListener`.

Is there really no specific listener for icons ?

From the Oracle tutorial : "Property-change events occur whenever the value of a bound property changes for a bean ??? a component that conforms to the JavaBeans™ specification."

```
buttonArray[a].addChangeListener("icon",new iconListener()); // doesn't work

buttonArray[a].addChangeListener("icon", new ImageIconListener()); // doesn't work
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing special to the *icon* property, it's just a ... property :-) So you need a custom PropertyChangeListener and register it with the button

```
PropertyChangeListener myListener = new PropertyChangeListener() .... {

};
// register to be only notified if the _icon_ property changes
button.addPropertyChangeListener("icon", myListener);
```

Comment: `// register to be only notified if the _icon_ property changes` refers to something like this right ? 
`      String propertyName = e.getPropertyName();
    if (e.getPropertyName().equals(AbstractButton.ICON_CHANGED_PROPERTY))`

Comment: basically, yes. But the property name doesn't need to be defined somewhere, just comply to the beans spec (sorry, don't have the link handy) - f.i. in `set/getSomeName` the property is `someName` and the bean must fire on changing it.

Answer (score 3):

- not there isn't specific [Listener for Icon / ImageIcon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14253786/714968)
- only its parent `JComponent` can to returns value from/to `(Property)ChangeListener`