# how can i receive the combobox arrow icon in windows plaf

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

how can i receive the combobox arrow icon in windows plaf
like that:

[image]

and add it to another JLabel as Icon

Comment: Do you need the exact icon shown in the image, or the one the platform l&f uses?

Comment: `how can i receive the combobox arrow icon in windows plaf like that` by mail? save as png file?

Answer (score 3):

1. AFAIK you can to use `new MetalComboBoxIcon()` directly, required only `import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxIcon;` you (never tried) have to search for equivalent in another L&Fs, no idea if you talking (windows plaf like that:) about `SystemL&F` (`Windows`) or `WindowsClassicLookAndFeel`
2. better ways are_

   - get `Icon` from `JComboBox`(loop in JComboBoxes `JComponent` there is `XxxComboBoxButton`) e.g. `MetalComboBoxButton`, this button contains `Icon`
   - look into `BasicComboBoxUI` or `WindowsComboBoxUI` (there is only about `paintIcon`), copy those code and create own class [for Icon by override paintIcon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14253786/714968)
   - create own `Icon`
   - I'b be use own `Icon` or `MetalComboBoxIcon` then result isn't L&F sensitive,

Comment: +1, thanks for correcting my response and pointing the OP in a better direction.